# Determining if the limit of a series is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose I have $F:D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $F$ uniformly converges to a continuous function f on D. My goal is to determine whether or not f is differentiable on D.

For a concrete example, let's say $F(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n/(n^3)$. We can use the M-test to see that F is uniformly convergent on $D = [-1,1]$. My goal is to tell if f (the limit of F) is differentiable on $[-1,1]$. Does it suffice to show that $F'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{n-1}/(n^2)$ converges uniformly on D?

My textbook offers the following theorem: "Let $f_n$ be differentiable functions defined on an interval D. Assume that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f'_n(x)$ converges uniformly to a limit $g(x)$ on D. If there exists a point $c\in D$ where $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(c)$ converges, then the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to a differentiable function $f(x)$ satisfying $f'(x) = g(x)$ on D."

So I guess my question boils down to: Since I already know $F(x)$ to be uniformly convergent, do I still need to find an explicit $c \in [-1,1]$ such that $F(c)$ converges in order to say that f is differentiable on D?

Comment: Analyticity is your friend.  If $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly on a region and $f_n$ is analytic on that region, that $f$ is also analytic on that region.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm entirely unfamiliar with the concept of being analytic.

Comment: It comes from complex analysis.  A function is analytic on a region $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$  if at every point of $U$ it has a convergent power series in a neighborhood of that point.  In particular - polynomials are analytic, so if polynomials converge uniformly on a region then the limit is automatically analytic (and hence continuous and infinitely differentiable.)

Comment: But - if you haven't studied complex analysis you'll have to use other methods.